# openssl encryption gives different output on different machines

Tags: encryption, openssl

I am encrypting the same message with the same cypher and the same password on different machines, but the result is each time totally different. How can I decrypt such a file on another machine then?

A minimal example:

```
echo "testmessage" > testfile
echo "mypwd" > pwdfile
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -A -salt -in testfile -out out -k pwdfile
cat out && echo
```

gives:

```
U2FsdGVkX1/vqur0facod4sMZs+ZT3i3yHe+DwAnV7o=
```

and

```
U2FsdGVkX18c6qnuSRrslmnneuDWAH1cp0UC4QyO5PI=
```

and other variants on still other machines

**EDIT**

I tried other cyphers as well (bf, cast, des3,...), only `base64` resulted in the same result on other machines. Yet I would need to decrypt an `aes-256-cbc` message encrypted on another machine.

Comment: This is due to the salt parameter.
Take a look at [OpenSSL - Password vs Salt Purpose][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297637/openssl-password-vs-salt-purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a non-issue; The result will be different each time something is encrypted. Decryption will work just fine; also across different machines.

The REAL problem causing my problem was the **path to the password file**:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -A -d -salt -in out -out outd -k pwdfile && cat outd
```

would nicely give me back my original file; but

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -A -d -salt -in out -out outd -k ./pwdfile && cat outd
```

fails with `Bad decrypt`; in fact not the contents of pwdfile were used, but pwdfile was the password.